# javascript table cell value user input and calculate total google script web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications

i am trying to made a grocer shop using google script web app feature. it uses javascript. click to see 
www.bit.ly/ctgshop
 In the table it shouws item name unit price quantity and total.
I like to take user inputs in the quantity column for all or some items.

in javascript i tried this >>>>>

==============================================

```
function generateTable(dataArray){

     var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

 dataArray.forEach(function(r){


 var row = document.createElement("tr");
 var col1 = document.createElement("td");
 col1.textContent = r[0];
 var col2 = document.createElement("td");
 col2.textContent = r[1];
 var col3 = document.createElement("td");
 col3.textContent = r[2];
 var col4 = document.createElement("td");
 col4.textContent = r[3];
 var col5 = document.createElement("td");
 col5.textContent = parseInt(document.createElement("input"));
 var col6 = document.createElement("td");
 col6.textContent = r[5];
 var col7 = document.createElement("td");
 col7.textContent = col5.textContent * col3.textContent;
 row.appendChild(col1);
 row.appendChild(col2);
 row.appendChild(col3);
 row.appendChild(col4);
 row.appendChild(col5);
 row.appendChild(col6);
 row.appendChild(col7);
 tbody.appendChild(row);


 });
```

## }

please help me to take user inputs to the table and it auto calculates to the total column and a grand total at the bottom. after that user will submit and all the order info will go to my google spreadsheet. thanks